# How to close the first opened radio button when other one selected using jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hi all i am working on jquery here i have three three radio buttons and i have three div for each selection i need to select
one dive like i had providing separate div for it when i selected the div it wil open right ok i need to perform like when 
i selected the other radio button the other one which opened first should close and selected should open how could i do this 
this is my code follows please help me to do this

```
                         <form class="form-horizontal" id="zone"> 
                           <label class="control-label" for="Availability">Shipping Zone Type</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" name="radio-1-set" id="radio-1-1"><label for="radio-1-1"></label>
                    This shipping zone is based on one more countries
                    <span class="tooltip-demo"><a data-original-title="Tooltip on right" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> </a></span>

                </label>

                <div class="selectbox-bg selectbox-bg-sb3 pull-left " id="shippingZone" style="display:none">
               <select>
                  <option>Choose a Country</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
               </select>
               </div> 
                           <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" name="radio-1-set" id="radio-1-2"><label for="radio-1-2"></label>                     
                    This shipping zone is based on one more state or provinces
                    <span class="tooltip-demo"><a data-original-title="Tooltip on right" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> </a></span>
                 </label>
                   <div class="selectbox-bg selectbox-bg-sb3 pull-left " id="shippingzonecountry" style="display:none">
               <select>
                  <option>Choose a Country</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
               </select>
               </div>
                  <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" name="radio-1-set" id="radio-1-3"><label for="radio-1-3"></label>                    
                 This shipping zone is based on one more postal or ZIP codes
                        <span class="tooltip-demo"><a data-original-title="Tooltip on right" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> </a></span>
                </label>
                <div class="selectbox-bg selectbox-bg-sb3 pull-left " id="zipcode" style="display:none">
               <select>
                  <option>Choose a Country</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
               </select>
               </div>  
                         </form>
```

in the above i have three radio bttons and three divs i need to select a radio button and it shoul b open 
 when i select the other the first which is opened it should be close plz help me to this sdtha

```
          thi is my jquery :as fpllows

                $(function () {
                 $("#radio-1-2").click(function () {
           $("#shippingzonestate").show('slow');
             });

          $("#radio-1-2").click(function () {
          $("#shippingzonestate").show('slow');
          $("#shippingzonecountry").show('slow');
           });

          $("#radio-1-3").click(function () {
         $("#zipcode").show('slow');
          $("#Product-Code-SKU").show('slow');
           });
```

i had tried like this but when i opened the other one should close how could i do this

Comment: Format your code appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**(Common function)

```
function showhide(radioname)
{
    $("#shippingzonestate").hide('slow');
    $("#shippingzonecountry").hide('slow');
    $("#zipcode").hide('slow');
    $("#Product-Code-SKU").hide('slow');

   if(radioname=="one")
   {
     $("#shippingzonestate").show('slow');
   }
   if(radioname=="two")
   {
     $("#shippingzonestate").show('slow');
     $("#shippingzonecountry").show('slow');
   }
   if(radioname=="three")
   {
     $("#zipcode").show('slow');
     $("#Product-Code-SKU").show('slow');
   }
}


$(function () {
                 $("#radio-1-2").click(function () {
                       showhide("one");
             });

          $("#radio-1-2").click(function () {
                        showhide("two");
           });

          $("#radio-1-3").click(function () {
                        showhide("three");
           });
});
```

---

just use [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method

```
  $(function () {
             $("#radio-1-2").click(function () {
       $("#shippingzonestate").show('slow');
        $("#shippingzonecountry").hide('slow');
          $("#zipcode").hide('slow');
      $("#Product-Code-SKU").hide('slow');
         });

      $("#radio-1-2").click(function () {
      $("#shippingzonestate").show('slow');
      $("#shippingzonecountry").show('slow');
          $("#zipcode").hide('slow');
      $("#Product-Code-SKU").hide('slow')
       });

      $("#radio-1-3").click(function () {
     $("#zipcode").show('slow');
      $("#Product-Code-SKU").show('slow');
      $("#shippingzonestate").hide('slow');
      $("#shippingzonecountry").hide('slow');
       });
```

Comment: thank you verymuch @pranay rana for my reply it's woring thank u

Comment: @shakil - dont forget to upvote answer and one more thing you can still modify this code in better way by creating common function...

Comment: how could i make common runction could u plz guide me